# Static Files not getting routed with IIS the same as they are with Cassini

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-2, cassini, virtualpathprovider

I have written a custom VirtualPathProvider for ASP.NET MVC 2 that searches assemblies for views and static content so that I can reuse content in multiple sites.  It works just fine while using Cassini, but when I deploy the site to a server running IIS 7, static files are just returning a 404 and not even getting routed through the AssemblyPathProvider (the class I wrote).  Does anyone know how to force IIS to work the same as Cassini in this regard?

Comment: A better approach is to use IIS during development for these scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

IIS and Cassini are definately two different beasts. I would agree with @Sayed in that you should try to opt to use IIS, especially since your production server is running IIS.

In that regard, I would further recommend that you use IIS Express for development. It is lightweight, and doesn't require admin privileged on your machine. It also behaves like IIS because it is IIS.

Here's some links for more info:

- http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx